# OS X El Capitan: man, command not found

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, command-line, bash

Today I was trying to update openssl in my MacBook Pro with El Capitan 10.11.2.
I don't know where I made a mistake but it seems I have accidentally disabled man. In fact, if I launch `man <something>` or `man man` or simply `man` it says --> `-bash: man: command not found`. Is there a way to restore it?

Some commands:

`which man` --> nothing

`file /usr/bin/man` --> man is a directory

I am afraid there's not an executable anymore.
In fact, with `ls -al /usr/bin/man` I got

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x     6 root  wheel    204 30 Dic 18:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  1063 root  wheel  36142 30 Dic 20:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x    46 root  wheel   1564 30 Dic 18:15 man1
drwxr-xr-x  1025 root  wheel  34850 30 Dic 18:15 man3
drwxr-xr-x     4 root  wheel    136 30 Dic 18:15 man5
drwxr-xr-x     3 root  wheel    102 30 Dic 18:15 man7
```

Comment: Try `which man` and `file /usr/bin/man` and update your question. :)

Comment: Ok, I have just added the command outputs

Comment: Okay I'm curious now. Run `ls -al /usr/bin/man` and update your question.

Comment: done...I'm really afraid I deleted the bin :(

Comment: With the other issues you had today it might be time to consider restoring from a Time Machine backup or a clean install of OS X.

Comment: I don't have a time machine :(

Comment: Clean install! The man dir including man1, man3... usually is here: /usr/share/man

Answer (score 1):

Apple publishes the source code for the open source parts of OSX. So the source for "man" is retrievable from https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/man/ .  The latest version (as of this writing) is v1.6c. Provided you have at least the Command Line Tools installed (you can run `xcode-select --install` to get them if you don’t):

```
curl -LORf 'https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/man/man-16.tar.gz'
tar -xzvf man-16.tar.gz
cd man-16/man

# Undo an Apple patch that adds a dependency on 'xcselect.h',
# which is something that Apple doesn't appear to distribute.
patch -R -p0 <../patches/PR11291804-xcode.diff

./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

That done, the `man` binary should be available at `/usr/local/bin/man`. Also note that you might need to run `hash -r` to clear the hash table of any instances of `/usr/bin/man` that may be lingering there from the last time you ran `man` before the addition to `/usr/local/bin/` will be picked up.

Comment: That's probably for the best. And don't be so hard on yourself. Only way I seem to be able to learn is by making lots of mistak... experiments. And believe me I've made lots and lots and lots of mistak... experiments, in my time. :)

Comment: You're right but this, in my opinion, is a terrible mistake and I am supposed to be a "computer scientist"...anyway, thank you for your help. And have a good 2016!! :)